# Vk sdk for android

Tags: android, vk

I want to make autorizathion with vk.com. I download [this](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk) library, but there is no normal exemple how to use it? I try next code, but it is not work for me.

```
 package ua.khuta.testVkSdk;

   import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
   import android.content.Intent;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import com.vk.sdk.*;
   import com.vk.sdk.api.VKError;

public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    /**
     * Called when the activity is first created.
     */


        private static String sTokenKey = "VK_ACCESS_TOKEN";
        private static String[] sMyScope = new String[]{VKScope.FRIENDS, VKScope.WALL, VKScope.PHOTOS, VKScope.NOHTTPS};
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            VKSdk.initialize(sdkListener, "id_приложения", VKAccessToken.tokenFromSharedPreferences(this, sTokenKey));
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            VKSdk.authorize(sMyScope, true, false);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();
            VKUIHelper.onResume(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            VKUIHelper.onDestroy(this);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            VKUIHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }

        private VKSdkListener sdkListener = new VKSdkListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCaptchaError(VKError captchaError) {
                new VKCaptchaDialog(captchaError).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onTokenExpired(VKAccessToken expiredToken) {
                VKSdk.authorize(sMyScope);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAccessDenied(VKError authorizationError) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this)
                        .setMessage(authorizationError.errorMessage)
                        .show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onReceiveNewToken(VKAccessToken newToken) {
                newToken.saveTokenToSharedPreferences(MyActivity.this, sTokenKey);
               // Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
               // startActivity(i);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAcceptUserToken(VKAccessToken token) {
                //Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
               // startActivity(i);
            }
        };

     }
```

Text of error

```
 03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): java.net.BindException: Context must not be null
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.checkConditions(VKSdk.java:90)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at com.vk.sdk.VKSdk.authorize(VKSdk.java:170)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at ua.khuta.testVkSdk.MyActivity.onCreate(MyActivity.java:23)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
03-27 16:42:16.189: WARN/System.err(19974): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-27 16:42:16.189: INFO/ActivityManager(593): Resuming delayed broadcast
```

Comment: do you get any errors?

Comment: _"there is no normal exemple how to use it"_ Right there on the page you linked to there are instructions for how to set things up, source code for an example application, and a library reference.

Comment: @nikis, Context must not be null in VKSdk.authorize(sMyScope, true, false);

Comment: @Michael, there is no sample how to use. I try to make somethink like that instruction, it does not woork

Comment: Post your stacktrace. Otherwise, it's difficult to figure out where you went wrong in your codes.

Comment: @ChuongPham, a have posted

Comment: @KostyaKhuta: First, you need to check line 90 of `VKSdk.java` class - as this is where the error occurred. Also, you need to pass a Context object into `VKSdk.java`. A context could be from an Activity, Service, etc. It looks like your context is null, so it failed at line 90

Comment: @KostyaKhuta have you done the steps from "UIHelper Applying" section?

Comment: @nikis, a add this section, look more carefull in my code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem happens because you didn't follow [UIHelper Applying](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk#uihelper-applying) section. The error you posted is pointing to the following piece of code:

```
if (sInstance.getContext() == null) {
    throw new BindException("Context must not be null");
}
```

So, let's take a look at the `getContext` method, it's very simple:

```
Context getContext() {
    return VKUIHelper.getTopActivity();
}
```

Why does it return `null`? Well, `VKUIHelper` is simple, take a look on [it](https://github.com/VKCOM/vk-android-sdk/blob/master/vksdk_library/src/main/java/com/vk/sdk/VKUIHelper.java) and you'll realize why (because `mTopActivity` is `null` without calling `VKUIHelper.onCreate()`)

Comment: yes, simply i add VKUIHelper.onCreate() in my onCreate method